# Force adb install to fail if manifest permissions not met

Tags: android, adb

The Galaxy Tab 2 7" wasn't showing up for us on the market and it turns out it was due to not having autofocus.

adb installs the apk on the device without throwing any complaints.

How can I force `adb install` to fail if the Manifest permissions are not satisfied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come across the same issue before. ADB is capabilities agnostic, but I found it helpful to check for required capabilities in Application.onCreate during development.

Comment: The answer you want is rarely the one you get but that's no fault of yours.  This solution is cumbersome but gets the job done.

Comment: Thanks for accepting it. On the upside, the Play Store approval process is nothing as cumbersome or slow as Apple's, so when issue like this surface, the fix is only hours away, rather than a week or more.